# Three mobile broadband fast speed test, but slow in safari and apps

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, internet-speed, mobile-broadband

I'm hoping this is the correct p[ace for this question...

I have Three 4G home broadband which consists of a Huawei 4g, sim card router and 4 BT whole home wifi mesh dishes to extend the signal through the house.

I'm having a weird problem - when I do a speed test, I'm constantly getting 40-60 Mbps - but on my phone if I open the weather app, instagram, tiktok, News etc... the images, video previews or information just doesn't load... I have to turn off WIFI and put on my phones 4G to get hem to load.

secondly on my computer, I'm a web designer so, I'm constantly refreshing websites after changes, I use safari (I know it might be strange!)... and quite often when refreshing sites and even when browsing they just won't load until I hit refresh a couple of times - like the just need a nudge to remember what they are supposed to be doing!

This seems a bit better on Chrome (not perfect), but Safari struggles...

I month ink its a safari settings or cache issue, as I've recently got myself a new MacBook and a fresh install of everything and I still get the same thing.

With these issues, I'm wondering if using mobile broadband has fundamental issues with my sort of usage or if there is some sort of problem I haven't thought of?

Three, my ISP, don't seem to be of any help... and I can't find anyone with the same issues online.

We can't get fast phone line speeds hence the need to go for the 4g router, but I don't understand why it would be fast speed tests and then not load inside apps on my phone or not load inside safari without needing to hit refresh a few times...

Does anyone have any ideas about what the issue could be?

Comment: This sounds like a DNS performance issue. Try switching DNS servers on your devices. Google's 8.8.8.8 and Cloudflare's 1.0.0.1 are good alternatives then retest.

Comment: Some providers game speed test sites by capping /shaping everything except those. You could also have a router/settings/MTU issue.

Comment: Try DSLReports speed test - they try to avoid the ISP 'go faster' stuff & have more detailed error reporting than most - https://www.dslreports.com/speedtest

Comment: Thanks all - I think Im going to try my DNS as 1.1.1.1 for a while and see what happens - Ive changed it on my router AND on my devices so ill see if its any better :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @davidgo I'm wondering about the MTU settings... its currently at 1440 - should I increase this? Could I just make it the max available size?

Comment: macOS should correctly set the MTU automatically using path MTU discovery

Comment: @Tetsujin isn’t MTU a setting on the router rather than my Mac?

Comment: it's on pretty much everything - your router is presumably pre-configged by your ISP & should be correct for their service, the Mac will definitely work it out for itself if left in auto mode

Comment: 1440 does seem very low - if you have it set on your devices then it is inefficient but unlikely the cause of the issue. If its set on your router but not other devices it could well be the cause of the issue if your router is not doing MTU clamping (and it likely isn't).

Comment: Thanks for these additional comments guys! I seem to still be having issues and still safari struggles with some sites where as chrome loads them fine - I've tried changing DNS on my router, (Cloudflare and google DNS) but I'm not sure it's being picked up... The MTU size is coming from my router - can I ask, What should the size be if 1440 is very low? Is there a set size I should change it too?